# How to grant "create test plan" rights for Visual Studio Team Services member?

Tags: azure-devops

I have a small (<5 users) team and we use Visual Studio Team Services for source control, backlog. There is some other functionality that I would like to use for my team - currently I,m trying to start using functionality for Tests.

I have possibility to create test plans, tests, but members of my team has only possibility to run those tests (they need rights to create tests).

I updated rights for the group (see the picture bellow, from VSTS configurations security tab), but still user has no possibility to create tests. Since I have these rights, it can not be restriction for the "free" version of VSTS, what am I missing? There must be a way to grant these rights without making that member an admin... Also I have not found any information that this functionality is not available for free edition (https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/products/visual-studio-team-services-vs.aspx), can anyone shed some light?

**EDIT**

This link on the other hand suggests, that Test functionality is limitted, but then I don't get why my account has functionality to create tests/test plans...

https://www.visualstudio.com/products/visual-studio-team-services-feature-matrix-vs
[image]

**The desired result** - I need Team members to have access to add new test plans (they have "Run" button, but no "New" button - the picture)

[image]

**This is what my Team member gets:**

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can follow the steps below to set the permission for "Manage test plans":

1. Open your project from Web Portal.
2. Click "Manage project" button in the up-right corner.
3. Open "Areas" panel in the settings.
4. Open the context menu of the root Area and select "Security".
5. Set "Manage test plans" permission to "Allow" for your users/groups. (You can click "Add..." button to add the users/groups if they are not listed in the dialog).

[image]

**Update:**

According to the screenshot you provided, Test Manager Extension isn't installed for these users. You can enable this feature for all users for 90 days and then you need to buy it for your users. Refer to this link for details: [Try Visual Studio Team Services extensions for free](https://www.visualstudio.com/get-started/setup/try-additional-features-vs)

And this feature will be available if the user use following Visual Studio subscriptions:

> Test Manager extension is included with these Visual Studio
>   subscriptions:
>
> Visual Studio Enterprise - monthly Visual Studio Enterprise - annual
>   Visual Studio Enterprise with MSDN MSDN Platforms Visual Studio Test
>   Professional with MSDN

Refer to this link for details: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms.vss-testmanager-web

Comment: ok, thanks - I'm waiting replay from the tester - will follow up here afterwards. P.S. This seems very strange - since in this security section that user was not present, but he is in the project team (he can do various stuff - create PBI items, comment etc.). I like VSTS very much, but this security configuration stuff seems to be not a good interface example...

Comment: Hmm... that was not enough. Now I added `Default collection->Security->Project Collection Valid Users` added `Manage test controllers = Allow`. I hope this will be enough...

Comment: adding rights for Project Collection Valid Users to Manage Test controllers also did not do the trick... :(

Comment: @Prokurors What's the behavior when they create test plan?

Comment: I did the changes you recommended, but unluckily my team member still did not get "New" button to create test plan... I edited post and added some images/information

Comment: @Prokurors Due to the comments limitation, please see the updates in my answer for details.